# How am I supposed to deal with new releases in Next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compatibility, next.js, next-i18next

I'm new to javascript world. One thing that sometimes terrifies me is the frequently changing libraries/frameworks. I started to learn Next js a month ago, when the latest version was 9.2. a few days later they released 9.3 with a lot of changes in documentation. (for example "getInitialProps" -> "getServerSideProps").

I want to use "next-i18next" for internationalization. If you see it's [docs](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next), there is no "getServerSideProps".

What is the best approach in this frequently changing javascript world?

You can see that [Next js docs](https://nextjs.org/) doesn't have documentation for a specific old version (for example 9.1).

How can we survive in this ecosystem?

Suppose that I start a project using Next js 9.3 now. How am I supposed to find specific documentations for version 9.3, a month later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Update your dependencies whenever it's possible.
2. Keep an old version if you have incompatibilities in dependencies.
3. Find a replacement for an incompatible dependency.

**The choice depends on the needs of your project**.

Usually, open source projects keep different versions of documentation, so people can access different docs depending on a version they use.

Next.js team has the documentation in the same GitHub repository , so you can find all versions of previous documentation.

For example [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/v9.2.2/docs) is the documentation for 9.2.2 version. You just need to choose a tag with your version.